# Could anyone help be with explaining the bold code?

Tags: tikz-pgf

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[x={(.7cm,-.3cm)}]
```

**`\path (1,0,0);
    \pgfgetlastxy{\cylxx}{\cylxy}
    \path (0,1,0);
    \pgfgetlastxy{\cylyx}{\cylyy}
    \path (0,0,1);
    \pgfgetlastxy{\cylzx}{\cylzy}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\cylt}{(\cylzy * \cylyx - \cylzx * \cylyy)/ (\cylzy\cylxx - \cylzx * \cylxy)}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\ang}{atan(\cylt)}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\ct}{1/sqrt(1 + (\cylt)^2)}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\st}{\cylt * \ct}`**

```
\fill[red] (\ct,\st,0) -- ++(0,0,-8) arc[start angle=\ang,delta angle=180,radius=1] -- ++(0,0,8) arc[start angle=\ang+180,delta angle=-180,radius=1];
\begin{scope}[every path/.style={ultra thick}]
\draw (0,0,0) circle[radius=1];
\draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (1,0,0);
\draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (0,1,0);
\draw (\ct,\st,0) -- ++(0,0,-8);
\draw (-\ct,-\st,0) -- ++(0,0,-8);
\draw (\ct,\st,-8) arc[start angle=\ang,delta angle=180,radius=1];
\draw[dashed] (\ct,\st,-8) arc[start angle=\ang,delta angle=-180,radius=1];
\end{scope}
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You had tagged this as lua but the question seems unrelated to Lua so I retagged it as tikz-pgf

Comment: You can read about all those commands in the [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf).

Answer (score 3):

First six lines define values for `\cylxx`, `\cylxy` , `\cylyx`, ...

[image]

Last four lines define values for `\cylt`, `\ang`, ...

[image]